# how to get rid of deprecated ciphers in FreeIPA?

Tags: security, freeipa

FreeIPA 4.8 deprecated a lot of old ciphers (https://freeipa.org/page/Releases/4.8.0). However, they are still in. Example:

```
# klist -ke /etc/krb5.keytab 
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1) 
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac) 
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac) 
   1 host/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac) 
   1 nfs/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 nfs/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 nfs/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1) 
   1 nfs/nasl006a.ac.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac)
```

Even hosts I had setup just a week ago (using version 4.9.11) still received deprecated ciphers. AFAICS they will be used, if both peers agree upon using a weak cipher.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1499119 promised, RHEL8 will take care of it by some system-wide policy, leaving users of other distros or operating systems in the rain. And FreeIPA's RFE#7256 ("user-friendly way to disable weak or deprecated ciphers", https://pagure.io/freeipa/issue/7256) is open for 5 years without visible progress.

Is there some way to tell FreeIPA to not create new secrets supporting the weak ciphers anymore?

What is the recommended procedure to finally get rid of the weak ciphers on all my 536 hosts? Something automatic would be nice.